# Function and tapply with errors

Tags: r, tapply

I am a student of economics in Brazil. I have a group of real estate data, neighborhoods, types of homes (apartments, houses, land), collecting dates (monthly), price, and we need to group them as follows:

by districts in each neighborhood types, and average prices of each period, something like this:

```
neighborhoods
...
    types,
    ...
        Sample dates prices
        ...
            List of real estate
            ...
```

With this arrangement, we need to check the price evolution in the analyzed peroxides.

Well, `tapply` function does it all automatically! However, my supervisor said I need to remove the outliers of the sample and apply certain filters in the subgroups. And for that, I apply a formula to each end group, because for a neighborhood or type, the results will be different.

Code:

```
   bairro <- c("B_FLORESTA", "B_PINHEIRAO", "B_PINHEIRAO", "B_PINHEIRINHO", 
                  "B_LUTHER KING", "B_LUTHER KING", "B_VILA NOVA", "B_VILA NOVA", 
                  "B_NOVA PETROPOLIS", "B_VILA NOVA", "B_INTERIOR", "B_ALVORADA", 
                  "B_SADIA", "B_SADIA", "B_SADIA", "B_SADIA", "B_SADIA", "B_SADIA", 
                  "B_SADIA", "B_JUPTER", "B_JUPTER", "B_FLORESTA", "B_ITALIA", 
                  "B_ITALIA", "B_ITALIA", "B_ITALIA")

      tipo <-   c("CASA", "CASA", "COMERCIAIS", "CASA", "CASA", "COMERCIAIS", 
                  "APARTAMENTO", "APARTAMENTO", "APARTAMENTO", "APARTAMENTO", 
                  "SITIO", "APARTAMENTO", "CASA", "CASA", "CASA", "CASA", 
                  "TERRENO", "TERRENO", "CASA", "CASA", "CASA", "CASA", 
                  "CASA", "CASA", "CASA", "CASA")

      valor <-  c(1167, 2500, 1125, 2286, 400, 400, 1500, 1500, 300, 1500, 555, 
                  973, 2500, 2556, 2500, 2556, 600, 850, 2338, 1857, 1857, 2000, 
                  2000, 2063, 2000, 2063)

      data <-   c("2015_07", "2015_07", "2015_07", "2015_07", "2015_07", "2015_07", 
                  "2015_07", "2015_07", "2015_08", "2015_08", "2015_08", "2015_08", 
                  "2015_08", "2015_08", "2015_08", "2015_08", "2015_08", "2015_08", 
                  "2015_09", "2015_09", "2015_09", "2015_09", "2015_09", "2015_09", 
                  "2015_09", "2015_09")

      dados <- data.frame(bairro, tipo, valor, data)
```

Loaded with it, I use the tapply () command to the filters using the sum () function.

```
tapply(dados$valor, list(dados$tipo, dados$data, dados$bairro), sum)
```

The output is this:

```
...
, , B_SADIA

        2015_07 2015_08 2015_09
APARTAMENTO      NA      NA      NA
CASA             NA   10112    2338
COMERCIAIS       NA      NA      NA
SITIO            NA      NA      NA
TERRENO          NA    1450      NA

, , B_VILA NOVA

        2015_07 2015_08 2015_09
APARTAMENTO    3000    1500      NA
CASA             NA      NA      NA
COMERCIAIS       NA      NA      NA
SITIO            NA      NA      NA
TERRENO          NA      NA      NA
```

The output is exactly what I need, however, instead of using the sum () function, use the tool below to get the same output as above:

```
    homo <- function (a){
        a <- a[order(a$valor),]
        n <- nrow(a)
        # sobra <- rep(NA, n -1)
          for(i in 1:n){
            a$sobra[i] = round(((a$valor[i+1] / a$valor[i])*100)-100, dig = 2)
          }
        a <- subset (a, a$sobra < 50)
        return (a)
      }
```

The homo () function is working, can be seen here:

```
homo(dados)
```

But when entering the homo () function in tapply, the output looks like this:

```
> tapply(dados$valor, list(dados$tipo, dados$data, dados$bairro), homo)
Error in a$valor : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
Called from: order(a$valor)
```

Well, this post, noble friend, what can I do to solve my situation?

Earnestly and thanking the outset,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function uses the dollar sign `$` syntax. It should not be used in functions in that way. You will need `a[,"valor"]` instead. But the function also uses columns that are not in the `tapply` output, so you will continue to receive errors when using it.

It appears that you can replace the function completely. With `dplyr` you can try:

```
library(dplyr)
dados %>% group_by(tipo, data, bairro) %>%
  arrange(valor) %>%
  mutate(sobra = round(((lead(valor) / valor)*100)-100, dig = 2)) %>%
  filter(sobra < 50)
```

---

**Edit**

If you are only removing outliers, you can try:

```
with(homo(dados), tapply(valor, list(tipo, data, bairro), sum))
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Pierre Lafortune, with a few additions to your code, it works perfectly.

Follows the final code:

```
      dados %>% group_by(tipo, data, bairro) %>%
                arrange(pvalor) %>%
                mutate(sobra = round(((lead(pvalor) / pvalor)*100)-100, dig = 2)) %>%
                filter(sobra < 50) %>%
                summarise(pvalor = mean(pvalor))
```